# slideDown multiple times

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-effects

I have a `click` event handler where I want a hidden `div` to slide down. I have achieved this, but rather than using a toggle and have it slide up on the additional `click`, I would like it to slide down again.

So, rather than slide down, slide up I want it to slide down and then slide down again.

This is the code I am currently using, until I manage to achieve the effect/animation I want:

```
$(document).ready(function() {      
    $(".whereami").click(function() {
       $(".currentpage").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

Comment: If you've used SO before, maybe you've seen http://jsfiddle.net/ before, why not set up some test code there?

Comment: Do you mean you want it to slide FURTHER down or reset and slide down the same way?

Comment: post in some jsfiddle.net and we'll help you out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i have read ur question like 5 times now ((: and solved your problem;

[here is demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PYttN/2/)

to keep up continuity animation, use this way;

```
  $(".whereami").click(function() {
      $(".currentpage").animate({'top':'+=100px'},600);//adds +100 on every click
  });                                          //and 600 for animation's duration
```

Comment: You can deal with stop(true,true) or stop(true) ?

Comment: i used stop(false, true) for hover evet, but on click it should be the same

Comment: Hi, sorry if I wasn't clear. So basically, it slides down to become visible, and instead of sliding up to become hidden again I want it to slide down. Just so that it has some continuity.

Comment: Brilliant, bit of tweaking and it'll be perfect. Thanks so much for your help, really appreciate it (It was driving me insane)